# How to find the mail server's database which stores usernames and passwds?

Tags: networking, server, email

Imagine we have an Email server on x@x.x.x.x. using ssh, we get access to the command-line. Now, how can we find the database in which data about users stored? Server is using Postfix and Dovecot!

Comment: but you do not tell us what database you are using :) are you installing mysql alongside? Oh and you need to set up the database yourself if mysql or postgress so why do you ask this quesion? See the related .conf file for dovevot that you set it up with.

Comment: hmmm ... Mysql is being used and the server is up and running for a few time so the database is set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dovecot-sql.conf`  should be the file that holds host, username and password.